# creating an xml file with <br> <a> tags in attributes

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

Hello

I am facing a unique predicament. I need to create an xml file for adding data to a dynamic flash website

The xml file shall have elements with attributes. AND the attributes values are required to have 
 tags and complete  link tags etc.

The attribute value is also required to have double quotes and italics around some text.

The idea is to create an xml file, the data through which is uploaded into a flash file. This data has to be styled in the attribute value.

I understand that XML for validation does NOT allow  and & like elements in attributes etc. BUT i have seen xml files with these values. They are probably created online as .php files..

PROBLEM:

1.  If i create an xml file with attributes having 
 tags etc, it cannot be parsed and there is an error.

2. How do i create a file that allows this and is validated?

3. Can it be created online using PHP etc?

4. CDATA cannot be used in attribute value, i think..

5. A sample of such a working file can be found at http://www.mayalin.com/flash_support/parent_data2_xml.php

Appreciating any input.

Thanks

Moody

Comment: it is a bad XML design to put data into attribute use attributes as description of the data not the data itself. For data create separate nodes and you wil avoid such "issues" e.g. `<element type="String"><![CDATA[THE DATA]]></element>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do i create a file that allows this and is validated?

Use character references for characters with special meaning.

`&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&quot;`, `&apos;`

> Can it be created online using PHP etc?

Any XML API should use character entities automatically (e.g. when you use a `setAttribute` method)